# Azure web role instance stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

We have a webrole running our application with two instances. One of the instances in one of our webroles just unexpectedly stopped. Initially, we thought it might be due to a role instance upgrade but it was down for more than an hour. It came up after an hour and went down again. We scaled up to three instances to see if the 3rd instance works ok. We found that instance 1 and 3 works fine but still the instance number 2 stops. Again, the other two instances seem fine. Does this mean that the VM instance is somehow corrupted?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to rdp into the machine yet, and check the event logs? Could be that there's something that prevents your instance from starting... (although, I would suspect it to through starting...stopping cycles then). Worth a look, though

Answer (score 2):

That certainly is unusual

To eliminate the possibility that it is just a dodgy instance you could try re-imaging it.  If you select the instance on the screen you've included the shot of it's an option on the bottom menu.